# EError parsing XML: mismatched tags

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to write an app on Eclipse. After change the scale type to matrices a parsing xml error appeared and it say its in line 169 but i cant see any error. I've looked up similar questions, but none are similar enough for me to know how to fix mine. I've looked through out my manifest and can't seem to find where the mismatched tag is.

Edit: I have tried the solutions given by you guys but the problem is still there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/editFormLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5px">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/formprepost" 
    />




<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/school"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:lines = "1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/psupervisor"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/school"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:lines = "1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/school" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pdate"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/psupervisor"
    android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"/>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ptick1"
    android:layout_width="540dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pdate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="154dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ptick2"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-11dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ptick1"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ptick1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ptick3"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ptick2"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ptick2" />




<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pcomment1"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tick1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ptick3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pcomment2"
    android:layout_width="614dp"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pcomment1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pcomment1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pcomment1"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"  />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/psignature1"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pdate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pcomment1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:background="#0000" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/psignature2"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/psupervisor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pcomment2"
    android:background="#0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added end tag for two `EditText` for **school** id and **psupervisor** id:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/school"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
android:background="#0000"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:maxLines = "1"
android:lines = "1"
android:layout_below="@+id/name" />  // Here

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/psupervisor"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/school"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:lines = "1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/school" />  // Here
```

Also, you need to use :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/editFormLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#FFF"
 android:orientation="vertical" > // Remove /> from here
```

Comment: Hii SID, me too working with his code and i identified the same what you said in your answer but know on line number 8 i.e. <ScrollView a error is pooping up stating "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." 

His XML don't have a root element. 

<A>...</A>
<A>...</A>

whereas it expected a root e.g.

<A>
   <B>...</B>
   <B>...</B>
</A>

XML documents must have root node

Comment: As Hariharan said, the user ended main RelativeLayout in starting itself like />.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Your ended main `RelativeLayout` in starting itself like `/>`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/editFormLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and also you have not close `EditText` for `school` and `psupervisor` id's just you have mention as `>` end like `/>` or `</EditText>`

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/school"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
android:background="#0000"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:maxLines = "1"
android:lines = "1"
android:layout_below="@+id/name" />  

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/psupervisor"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/school"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle1"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines = "1"
    android:lines = "1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/school" />
```